# How to insert list box dynamically on click of a button in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to create a table for inserting multiple rows of data to the database.I have a field where I can insert a number and click on "Add" button. No of records will be added to the table.

I can add number of records now based on the rowcount inserted. But I want Floor_id field to be sequential numer whereas it is only copyig first field.

Can anyone guilde how to get first field as incremental number.

**Code Snippet**

```js
function addRow(tableID,num)
  { 
    
   var num = $("#rownum").val();
     $("#dataTable tr").slice(2).remove();
   for (var n = 2; n <= num; n++) 
   {
     var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
     var rowCount = table.rows.length;
     var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
     var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
     for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) 
     {
      var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
      newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
      //alert(newcell.childNodes);
      switch(newcell.childNodes[1].type) 
      {
       case "text":
         newcell.childNodes[1].value = "";
         break;
       case "select-one":
         newcell.childNodes[1].selectedIndex = 0;
         break;
      }
     }
   }
  }
```

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div class="results"></div>
  
  <fieldset style="width: 1600px;">
   <legend><b>Building Layout Info</b></legend>
   <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>Floor_Id</th>
    <th>Front_F_Mark </th>
    <th>Rear_F_Mark</th>
    <th>Floor_Type</th>
   </tr>
   <TR>
     <td><input type= "text" name= "Floor_Id[]" value="1"  /> </td>
     <td><input type= "text" name= "Front_F_Mark[]"  /> </td>
     <td><input type= "text" name= "Rear_F_Mark[]" /> </td></td>
     <td><select  name="Floor_Type[]" id="Floor_Type"  >  <br />
        <option value="">Floor_Type </option>
        <option value="Normal">Normal</option> 
        <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option> </select>  
      </select>
     </td>
   </TR>
<labe>Number of Records<input class="row" type='text' id='rownum' name='rownum' /> </label>
 <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable');" />
</TABLE>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post codes and efforts –

Comment: @bub thanks for mentioning that . Updated the same.

Comment: @ItamarG3 can you help about how to add list box, as its adding only text boxes here .My list box is fetching data through PDO..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to acheive this through following changes .

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
  <div class="results"></div>

    <fieldset style="width: 1600px;">
        <legend><b>Building Layout Info</b></legend>
        <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Floor_Id</th>
            <th>Front_F_Mark </th>
            <th>Rear_F_Mark</th>
            <th>Floor_Type</th>
        </tr>
        <TR>
             <td><input type= "text" name= "Floor_Id[]" value="1"  /> </td>
             <td><input type= "text" name= "Front_F_Mark[]"  /> </td>
             <td><input type= "text" name= "Rear_F_Mark[]" /> </td></td>
             <td><select  name="Floor_Type[]" id="Floor_Type"  >    <br />
                         <option value="">Floor_Type </option>
                         <option value="Normal">Normal</option> 
                         <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option> </select>  
                    </select>
             </td>
        </TR>
       <labe>Number of Records<input class="row" type='text' id='rownum' name='rownum' /> </label>
      <button type="button" class='loadfloor' style="float: right;"> Load Floors</button>
      </TABLE>   
     </form>
     <script>   
     $(".loadfloor").on('click',function(){
    var num = $("#rownum").val();
    $("#dataTable tr").slice(2).remove();
    for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++) 
    {
        var data = "<tr><td><input type='text' id='Floor_Id"+i+"' name='Floor_Id[]' value = "+i+" /></td><td><input type='text' id='Front_F_Mark"+i+"' name='Front_F_Mark[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='Rear_F_Mark"+i+"' name='Rear_F_Mark[]'/></td><td><select id='Floor_Type"+i+"' name='Floor_Type[]'><option value='null'>Floor_Type</option><option value='Normal'>Normal</option><option value='Hidden'>Hidden</option></td></tr>";
        $("#dataTable").append(data);
    }
 }); 
  </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```